# how to optimize several "WHERE (Select .... ) = value" from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-optimization

It's hard to compose a topic name for me. But I can show an example :

```
WHERE   (SELECT [ID_Line] FROM [Event] WHERE [Event].[Name]  = [A].[Col]) = 2
AND     (SELECT [DataType] FROM [Event] WHERE [Event].[Name]  = [A].[Col]) = 2
```

Here I'm processing 2 queries when I really need something like that :

```
WHERE   (SELECT [ID_Line],[DataType] FROM [Event] WHERE [Event].[Name]  = [A].[Col]) = 2,2
```

but SQL doesn't work with tuples, so must I make **Inner Join** here ?

Comment: @gbn ms sql 2008 express

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try something like this :

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT [ID_Line] FROM [Event] WHERE
        [Event].[Name]  = [A].[Col] AND
        [Event].[ID_Line] = 2 AND
        [Event].[DataType] = 2
)
```

If you provide more information about the complete query and your database structure, a more precise answer could be given. It is possible that this isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to melt the fields using a melting operator.  In ORACLE PL/SQL you use || (double pipe), for example.